# SQL query is running very slow. It shows the results in about 23 seconds

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

The following SQL query is running very slowly. It prints the results to the screen in about 23 seconds. What can I do to make the query run faster.

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.*,U.*
        FROM i_friends F FORCE INDEX(ixFriend)
            INNER JOIN i_posts P FORCE INDEX (ixForcePostOwner)
            ON P.post_owner_id = F.fr_two
            INNER JOIN i_users U FORCE INDEX (ixForceUser)
            ON P.post_owner_id = U.iuid AND U.uStatus IN('1','3') AND F.fr_status IN('me', 'flwr', 'subscriber')
        WHERE P.post_owner_id='$uid' $morePost
        GROUP BY P.post_id
        DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: DISTINCT is more expensive. Though I'm not sure what its purpose is if it's doing a distinct of all columns anyway?

Comment: You should look at the query plan and see what is actually happening. That will tell you if indexes are actually being used, etc. See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html

Comment: FORCE INDEX(ixFriend) is that actually better then the optimisers choice? AND group by with no aggregate funtions is not a good thing..And nor is the group by with order by..

Comment: When you ask a question about query-optimization, you should include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for the table(s) in the query, so we don't have to guess which data types, indexes, and constraints you have defined. Even better would be a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.co.uk) so we can test your query. Help us to help you!

Comment: Adding to @BillKarwin's point: We need the approximate number of rows in each table, the version of MySQL/MariaDB, and the execution plan (the output from ANALYZE or EXPLAIN ANALYZE if possible, EXPLAIN if not) *without* any FORCE INDEX directives. (Situations where FORCE INDEX directives actually help performance are vanishingly rare.)  And your WHERE and ORDER BY clauses seem to have syntax errors.

Comment: @P.Salmon - JOIN + GROUP BY is a use case that does not involve aggregates; see "explode-implode" in my Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- These look like "filters", so move them to the `WHERE` clause and leave just "relation" conditions in the `ON` clause.  (This won't change performance, but will make reading the query easier.)

  ```
      AND  U.uStatus IN('1','3')
      AND  F.fr_status IN('me', 'flwr', 'subscriber')
  ```
- Get rid of the `FORCE INDEX` clauses; they may help today, but hurt tomorrow when the distribution of the data changes.
- What is `$morePost`?  I ask because it may be critical to optimizing the performance.
- Add these composite indexes:

  ```
  P:  INDEX(post_owner_id, post_id)
  F:  INDEX(fr_status, fr_two)
  U:  INDEX(uStatus, iuid)
  ```

(When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.  That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.)

- Don't use both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`; it probably cause an extra sort on the entire dataset (after the JOINs, but before the LIMIT).
- `LIMIT 5` without an `ORDER BY` lets the Optimizer pick whichever 5 it likes.  Add an `ORDER BY` if you care which 5.
- A common performance problem comes from the mixture of `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.  I call it "explode-implode".  The Joins explode the data set into lots more rows, only to have the Group-by implode back down to the rows that came from one of the tables.  The typical cure is first select the desired rows from the grouped table (`P`).  Do this in a "derived table".  then Join to the other tables.  (However, I got lost in this query, so I cannot tell if it applies here.)